# Why pandas convert UNIX timestamps to multiple different date-time values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a pandas dataframe with UNIX timestamps (these are integers and not time objects).  I'd like to convert the UNIX timestamps into local time (according to China timezone).
So, based on this, I tried to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'timestamp':  [1540651297,  1540651300, 1540651303,  1540651306,  1540651309,  1540651312]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['timestamp'])
df
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='s')
df['timestamp2']=df['timestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['timestamp3'] = df['timestamp1'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Shanghai').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

| timestamp | timestamp1 | timestamp2 | timestamp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1540651297 | 2018-10-27 14:41:37 | 2018-10-27 22:41:37 | 2018-10-27 06:41:37+00:00 |
| 1540651300 | 2018-10-27 14:41:40 | 2018-10-27 22:41:40 | 2018-10-27 06:41:40+00:00 |
| 1540651303 | 2018-10-27 14:41:43 | 2018-10-27 22:41:43 | 2018-10-27 06:41:43+00:00 |
| 1540651306 | 2018-10-27 14:41:46 | 2018-10-27 22:41:46 | 2018-10-27 06:41:46+00:00 |
| 1540651309 | 2018-10-27 14:41:49 | 2018-10-27 22:41:49 | 2018-10-27 06:41:49+00:00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='s')
```

This statement here creates a column with datetime value with current time. The datetime values are time-zone naive and in UTC.

```
df['timestamp2']=df['timestamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` takes in a timestamp and returns a local datetime. For `ASIA/Shanghai`, the offset from UTC would be +8. The datetime values are still time-zone naive.

```
df['timestamp1'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Shanghai')
```

This returns a Series with time-zone aware datetime using time-zone naive one(`timestamp1`).

`2018-10-27 14:41:37` becomes  `2018-10-27 14:41:37+08:00`.

```
df['timestamp1'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Shanghai').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

The `dt.tz_convert('UTC')` converts tz-aware datetime from one time zone to another.
`2018-10-27 14:41:37+08:00` is converted to UTC datetime with time-zone as `2018-10-27 06:41:37+00:00`.
What you should have done instead is

```
df['timestamp3'] = df['timestamp1'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')
```

Which converts the time zone naive UTC datetime to time zone aware UTC datetime and then to the `Asia/Shanghai` time-zone
The result would be:

| timestamp | timestamp1 | timestamp2 | timestamp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1540651297 | 2018-10-27 14:41:37 | 2018-10-27 22:41:37 | 2018-10-27 22:41:37+08:00 |
| 1540651300 | 2018-10-27 14:41:40 | 2018-10-27 22:41:40 | 2018-10-27 22:41:40+08:00 |
| 1540651303 | 2018-10-27 14:41:43 | 2018-10-27 22:41:43 | 2018-10-27 22:41:43+08:00 |
| 1540651306 | 2018-10-27 14:41:46 | 2018-10-27 22:41:46 | 2018-10-27 22:41:46+08:00 |
| 1540651309 | 2018-10-27 14:41:49 | 2018-10-27 22:41:49 | 2018-10-27 22:41:49+08:00 |